# Why isn't parseInt(String) method giving an error when the String contains a " - " minus sign?

Tags: java

So I was looking into a solution for an exercise and found it wierd that it wasn't giving an error and was actually ignoring it.

code:

Initializing a bank account object(just a snap of the code since this is the essential part):

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[3];
try{

accounts[0] = new SavingAccount("035-0621094-44", 2.5);
```

A part of the validation of the bank account number and splitting it up:

```
private void isNrOk (String nr) throws AccountException{

    if (nr.length()==14){
         int d1=Integer.parseInt(nr.substring(0,3));
         System.out.println(d1);
```

Output: 35

So my question is, why is it not giving me and error when I'm trying to convert the string '035-' into an integer. I thought if you tried to convert something other than decimals it would give an error. Or is it because it's seen as a minus sign and simply ignores it in this instance because its at the back?

edit: I didn't know about the javadocs, should have looked there appearantly.
thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: because it doesn't contain a "-". you only check the first three chars, being "035".
But, if you want to split the parts up, using String's split method would be easier.

Comment: you can split your string by '-' and then use parseInt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not parsing 035- but 035, as it is from the character at index zero until the third value; hence 035.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because:

```
scala> "035-0621094-44".substring(0, 3)
res4: String = 035
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm not sure which question you are talking about; I replied to this one: _"So my question is, why is it not giving me and error when I'm trying to convert the string '035-' into an integer."_

Comment: I don't see how you replied to the question. You may mean the correct thing, but as you wrote it, it doesn't answer it.

Comment: It's just a compact way of saying what the accepted answer is saying — what is it that's bothering you?

Comment: Look, I got this answer for review and I stated my problem with it. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code also.

```
String[] stringArr = nr.split("-");
int d1 = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[0]);
```

Comment: I know about the String.split() method, was just confused about something in the String.substring() method.

Answer (score 0):

***substring***

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,
               int endIndex)
```

This method returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex. 
Examples:

```
"hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
 "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Substring constructor used with begin index and end index.

But while you will apply substring on string you need to consider the begin index on 0 based and end index on 1 based.

You can also split based on '-'.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the base syntax....

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

For Example:

```
String Str = new String("AccontNumber: 1234-2234-123");


  for (String s: Str.split("-", 2)){
     System.out.println(s);
```